# Array em PHP usando () ou []?

Tags: php, array, sintaxe

Eu sempre uso os parênteses para definir uma array em PHP, tal como:

```
$array = array('a','b','c');
```

Mas vez em quando vejo alguns códigos aqui usando colchetes, como:

```
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

No entanto, se eu usar colchetes, obtenho o erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in...

Qual a forma correta? Tem alguma coisa a ver com a versão do PHP? Qual versão aceita uma coisa e outra?

Ao dar um `echo phpversion();` numa página PHP da minha hospedagem obtenho a seguinte versão:

> 5.2.17

Comment: Acredito que seja a versão, no meu (7.1.15) está funcionando normalmente

Comment: Tinha acabado de ver isso, apesar de gostar do uso com colchetes, estou usando os parêntesis, nunca se sabe se a hospedagem irá suportar.

Comment: Eu não sabia disso http://www.linuxformat.com/dvdsupport

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Segundo a documentação, [*Short array syntax*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration54.new-features.php) foi adicionada na versão *5.4.0 do PHP*:

```
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Ao executar o código acima em uma versão inferior à *5.4*, obterá o erro informado, já a outra notação, foi adicionada na versão *4 do PHP* a qual a [documentação já foi removida](http://php.net/manual/php4.php).

> *Qual a forma correta?*

As duas são corretas se estiverem sendo utilizadas em uma versão compatível!

> *Qual versão aceita uma coisa e outra?*

```
# PHP 4 ~> 7.x
$array = array('a','b','c');

# PHP 5.4.x ~> 7.x
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Comment: Pois eh, minha hospedagem tá atrasadíssima. Valeu pela resposta. muito boa!

Comment: MAs aproveitando, me tira uma dúvida: essa versão que uso ainda é boa ou tah ruim mesmo?

Comment: Ta ruim mesmo rs.

Comment: Você pode escolher a versão que deseja! Mas sinceramente, eu não teria essa opção, uma vez que versão mais recentes tem correções e melhorias, eu daria apenas a versão *5.6* e a *7.x* para escolha. Mas, olhando para o **ganho** quem se importa né ?